# jEditable edit multiple cells of a table simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jeditable

I am trying to make multiple cells of an html table row be editable by clicking on that row using jEditable.

However, the default behaviour of jEditable seems to be that at a given time, it allows only one element to stay editable. In my example above, the elements are `<td>`s

HTML:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr id="row1" class="row">
        <td class='editme'>Test11</td>
        <td class='editme'>Test12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" class="row">
        <td class='editme'>Test21</td>
        <td class='editme'>Test22</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$("td.editme").editable("nothing",{
    event : "make_cell_editable",
})
$('.row').live('click', (function () { 
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('make_cell_editable');
    });

}));
```

I have created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EMSdN/7/

Can anyone suggest a solution?